# How to insert a block of code between two specific html tags with a shell script?

Tags: html, shell

I need to insert a block of code (in fact it is an adsense ads script) between two specific tags (html file) that are the following:

```
</style>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
```

I need to insert it in the **THIRD occurrence** of these two labels.
The form of a typical Adsense block is:

```
<script async 
  src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"> 
</script>
<script>
 lorem ipsum...                          
</script>
```

In the end I need to have something like this:

```
</style>

 <script async 
  src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"> 
  </script>
  <script>
   lorem ipsum...                            
  </script>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
```

I have inserted blocks of code using `sed` and indicating the line number, in this case it is not possible in this way because the line number can change.
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: `awk '/pattern to match/{match_count++} {if (match_count==3) {print "your extraStuff"}1' htmlfile > new.htmlfile` will give you something to experiment and search further on. The `1` after the closing `}` indicates 'print all input". Remove that to experiment. You can add explicit instructions on when to print input, using more `{if{...}else{}}` logic. Spend a few hours with the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and you'll be on your way to `awk` guruhood ;-) Good luck.

Comment: But this all assumes you have control over the creation of your `html` output. `html` should really only be parsed with an `html` aware parser. Once and element breaks across lines, `awk` will cry fowl, as it is a line based parser, not an `<tag> ...</tag>` .. parser. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shellter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if you can use bash. This solution is not very fast, but it should work.

**insert_rubbish.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

StartPattern='</style>'
StopPattern='<table border="1" class="dataframe">'

content=$(cat << EOT
<script async
  src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script>
<script>
 lorem ipsum...
</script>
EOT
)

# loop over all lines
while read -r line; do

    # if pattern found
    if [[ $line =~ $StopPattern && $lastline =~ $StartPattern ]]; then

       # is it the third fund? --> then print content
       if [[ $count == 2 ]]; then
          printf "%s\n" "$content"
       fi

       # count pattern match
       (( count++ ))
    fi

    # write line
    printf "%s\n" "$line"

    # save line for next pattern match
    lastline="$line"
done < "$1"
```

**Usage**

```
insert_rubbish.sh "/path/to/your/file.html" > output.html
```

Comment: Hello @UtLox:
Your script is awesome, it worked perfectly.
It is also a very robust script because you only have to change the pattern to make various inserts!
I will keep the name you gave him and your authorship! Thank you!